# android content activitynotfoundexception no activity found to handle intent - when trying to go to url

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to write an app where you can type in an address and then you get redirected to google maps. (I suppose this is called implicit intent)

-I have created an intent to launch the main activity, which is the only activity in my app.
The Main activity consists of some text, an editfield and a button.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.where_do_you_live"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

this is the code for the button:

```
public void Button1Click(View view)
{       
    try
    {
        addressField=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.address);

        String address=addressField.getText().toString();
        address=address.replace(' ','+');
        Intent geoIntent=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + address));
        startActivity(geoIntent);

    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(e.toString());
        //finding stuff

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have google maps installed on your device?

Comment: the device is an emulator so do I have to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are testing this in emulator, things are different than in a device.

When you are creating your Android Virtual Device, you should select Google APIs as your target. If you do not have them installed, you can use SDK Manager to download it.

Have a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/).

[image]

Comment: i faced this problem in real device when i show point in google map and  press the botton of google