# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent google map

Tags: android, android-intent

i am learning how to use goolge maps in android app. as part of this i  am following courseera. in that i found one app. This application will take user address as input and show the its location in map using intents. I used a buttion onclicklistner

```
button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                String address = addrText.getText().toString();
                address = address.replace(' ', '+');
                Intent geoIntent = new Intent(
                               android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                                       .parse("geo:0,0?q=" + address));
                startActivity(geoIntent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            }
        }
```

my manifest file

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" >
</uses-sdk>

<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="MapLocation" >
    <activity
        android:name="course.examples.MapLocation.MapLocation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

my log cat view

```
04-12 18:28:46.446: E/MapLocation(567): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=geo:0,0?q= }
04-12 18:28:46.636: E/MapLocation(567): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=geo:0,0?q= }
04-12 18:28:46.886: E/MapLocation(567): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=geo:0,0?q= }
04-12 18:28:47.975: E/MapLocation(567): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=geo:0,0?q= }
04-12 18:28:49.055: E/MapLocation(567): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=geo:0,0?q= }
04-12 18:28:49.217: E/MapLocation(567): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=geo:0,0?q= }
04-12 18:28:49.885: E/MapLocation(567): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=geo:0,0?q= }
04-12 18:28:50.265: E/MapLocation(567): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=geo:0,0?q= }
04-12 18:58:17.797: I/dalvikvm(567): Jit: resizing JitTable from 512 to 1024
04-12 20:10:13.078: E/MapLocation(567): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=geo:0,0?q= }
04-12 20:10:13.326: E/MapLocation(567): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=geo:0,0?q= }
04-12 20:10:13.515: E/MapLocation(567): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=geo:0,0?q= }
04-12 20:10:14.396: E/MapLocation(567): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=geo:0,0?q= }
```

Comment: can you post your logcat?

Comment: and your Manifest.xml

Comment: Show us the manifest.

Comment: there is no need to see manifest ... question is if map application is installed on device/emulator ...

Comment: here is my manifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="course.examples.MapLocation"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" >
    </uses-sdk>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="MapLocation" >
        <activity
            android:name="course.examples.MapLocation.MapLocation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android content activitynotfoundexception no activity found to handle intent - when trying to go to url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525666/android-content-activitynotfoundexception-no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-w)