# ActivityNotFoundException when press on buttons on google map

Tags: google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-markers, activitynotfoundexception

[image]

when press on buttons on google map at fragment this ActivityNotFoundException  occurs,

```
enter code here     android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=geo:31.45133712274478,34.388197772204876?z=2.0&q=31.4513371,34.3881978(مسجد الفاروق) flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.google.android.apps.maps }
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1660)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1430)
                                                   at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1396)
                                                   at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1378)
                                                   at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:318)
                                                   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.eu.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.eu.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.ae.onClick(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4639)
                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19252)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android content activitynotfoundexception no activity found to handle intent - when trying to go to url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525666/android-content-activitynotfoundexception-no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-w)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It occurs because I disabled google map app from my android mobile. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing this or simply:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.ae.onClick(Unknown Source)
```

And you're not fussy about providing the navigation options, then it may be worth removing them:

```
gMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
```