# Unable to launch navigation intent from Wear 2.0 device

Tags: android, google-maps, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I am currently testing the wear 2.0 capabilities, and decided to go through the new maps implementation.

I tried to launch a quite basic navigation intent from the info window click of a marker, but the app keeps crashing with an unexpectedly weird error.

my code:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    // Map is ready to be used.
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Set the long click listener as a way to exit the map.
    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + marker.getPosition().latitude+","+marker.getPosition().longitude);
            Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
            startActivity(mapIntent);
        }
    });
    // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia and move the camera.
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

the error i keep getting:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=google.navigation:q=-34.0,151.0 }

Am i doing something wrong?  running on a wear 2.0 android O emulator.

Comment: Are you sure the watch (or emulator) has an app with an activity that can handle the ACTION_VIEW intent filter? What app (or activity) are you expecting to open? If the activity is part of your app, verify that it has the ACTION_VIEW intent filter in the manifest.

Comment: i am expecting google maps built in navigation system to launch. it should exist, right?

Comment: Just to verify: You have Google Maps installed on your test device? I would imagine so, but crazier things have happened. Can you run the app stand alone separate from your code here?

Comment: yup, it launches, shows a marker. then i added that intent on the marker, and on info window click, it crashes,ç

Comment: thank god i was just testing this,  what a hell of a bad support for wear2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wear 2.0 maps system didn't include navigation per se, that's why it crashed. Apparently it's getting added in the upcoming Watch OS.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking through the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#launch_turn-by-turn_navigation) on this and noticed one difference. In the Google API docs, they have a line that explicitly sets the package of the app they want to launch. Your code doesn't have that:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Taronga+Zoo,+Sydney+Australia");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Try adding in the third line from the above snippet, and see if that launches the proper application.

Answer (score 0):

[`ActivityNotFoundException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ActivityNotFoundException.html) is thrown when a call to [`startActivity(Intent)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) or one of its variants fails because an Activity can not be found to execute the given Intent. You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525666/android-content-activitynotfoundexception-no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-w) which stated that when creating your Android Virtual Device, you should select [Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview) as your target. If you do not have them installed, you can use SDK Manager to download it.

Comment: the map launches. what doesn't launch is the navigation intent.